# Display label in custom control used on an ASP.Net aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I am using a Custom control in my aspx page. This custom control has a error message label. I need to display this label from the code behind on button click. How can i achieve this.

Button and custom control is in Update panel.

Comment: Do you have any code that you can show us? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean a UserControl or CustomControl?

Comment: Thanks i got the solution using ScriptManager http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that in the custom control you have the label you want to show and the button you have on the update panel outside the custom control.

If so, you should create a public method in your Custom control, something like `public void ShowError(string message)` and when you do the button click you call this method passing the text to display. In the method implementation inside the custom control you will assign the message text to the label and display the label if not visible. This should actually work either you use an update panel or not as long as both button and custom control are at the same time outside or inside the `UpdatePanel` but not one in and the other out.